# JS: парсинг стека ошибки полученного с прода

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
У меня есть стандартное SPA с реактом.
Разумеется для сборки я использую webpack, babel и т.д.
На выходе для prod сервера я имею минимизированный JS.
В случае вылетания ошибки (которые я перехватываю и скидываю на сервер) я получаю error.stack, который ссылается на минимизированный код.
Естественно читать это невозможно и разобарться в этом нереально.
У меня есть возможноть хранить на сервере sourcemaps для каждой версии.

А дальше встает вопрос. Как на сервере используя sourcemaps распарсить стек ошибки, которая пришла с продакшна?

Я нашел библиотечку (retrace), которая делает примерно это. Но из минусов: она лезет за bundle.min.js на сервер. При этом sourcemaps ей можно подсунуть прям на сервере. Таким образом отсутствует возможность распарсить ошибку, которая произошла какое-то время назад (если версия после этого обновилась).
Это довольно плохо, так как не хочется парсить все подряд ошибки, а так же хочется парсить еще и старые.

Вопрос: как парсить стек пришедший с прода использую sourcemaps на сервере?

Comment: 1. Писать детализированные логи. 2. Попробовать воспроизвести ошибку на деве

Comment: Вы вероятно не совсем правильно поняли суть. 
С прода пришла ошибка. Т.к. на проде нету sourcemaps, то она ссылается на минимизированный bundle.js.
Дальше эту ошибку нужно перевести в адекватный вид используя sourcemaps, которые на сервере все таки есть.

Соответственно писать детализированные логи - куда, откуда? Клиент поймал ошибку, какие там уже логи куда писать?
Чтобы воспроизвести ошибку на деве, надо её разобрать, а в этом и проблема.